# Why does the SharedWorker onConnect event have a Ports array?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, shared-worker

In all examples I've seen, they're similar to this

```
onconnect = function(e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];

    port.onmessage = function(e) {
        var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
        port.postMessage(workerResult);
    }

    port.start();
}
```

Is there an instance where the ports array will ever have more than one element? Using chrome://inspect on the SharedWorker and printing out `e`, I get

[image: MessageEvent]

regardless of how many instances are spawned sharing the SharedWorker, where the length is always 1. Why isn't it just a MessageEvent instead of an array? What use case is there for it to be an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that it reuses the `MessageEvent` interface which can sometimes be dispatched with an array of multiple ports. That's all.

Comment: and what cases would that be? using websockets? I'm super curious.

Comment: Using `window.postMessage` you can pass in an array of ports in the `transfer` argument. See 
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#introduction-12
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#ports-as-the-basis-of-an-object-capability-model-on-the-web